# Can't save Site as Template on a publishing site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, site-template, publishing, save-as-template

I understand that you can't save a site as a template if Publishing is turned on.

My question is...Why is this? Is this a bug or is this by design.  Is the workaround as simple as turning to publish off, saving as a template, and turning to publish back on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Is this a bug or is this by design?**

It's by design,

[image]

The simple reason according to Microsoft is that “the publishing feature creates site elements that are not supported as part of a template, and these elements remain even when the feature is disabled. This also includes templates that were created through SharePoint Designer.”  [Ref](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/missing-save-site-as-template-option-in-sharepoint-online-office-365-and-sharepoint-server-2013/)

- **Unsupported**    Customized permissions, running workflow instances, list item version history, workflow tasks associated with running workflows, people or group field values, taxonomy field values, publishing sites and pages, and stapled features.
- **Supported**    Lists, libraries, external lists, data source connections, list views and data views, custom forms, workflows, content types, custom actions, navigation, site pages, master pages, modules, and web templates.

For more details check,

- [Missing “Save Site As Template” Option in SharePoint Online, Office 365 and SharePoint Server 2013](https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/missing-save-site-as-template-option-in-sharepoint-online-office-365-and-sharepoint-server-2013/).
- [Missing Save Site as a template](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)
- [Create and use site templates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-use-site-templates-60371b0f-00e0-4c49-a844-34759ebdd989).

**Is the workaround as simple as turning to publish off, saving as a template, and turning to publish back on?**

**No,** it's not a solution, The site that has ever had Publishing features enabled can’t be saved as a template. and most of all workaround will be failed,

> **Note:** Any workaround over the internet to `‘Save site as a template‘` from a Publishing Site or from a site that has ever had publishing
>   features enabled is **unsupported** and often doesn’t work.

**For more details,** please Check, at [Missing Save Site as a template](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)

Comment: Mohamed, can you explain why it's by design.  I can't wrap my head around that.  Thanks

Comment: @MartinMuldoon Actually, **Why it's by design?** question is so difficult to be answered directly specifically if there is no official reason announced from Microsoft, I have tried to collect some info in the above-updated answer, hope it helps you :)

Comment: Hi Mohamed.  Thanks again for answering this.  Just a quick follow up.  So w/ publishing activated, we've lost the ability to save Site as Template.  If the IT group keeps pushing, do you think a third party migration tool performs this same function?  I know we aren't allowed to push products on this site, but any thoughts on this?